# Cultivation martial arts manwha where the kid is reborn in a demon sect and is trained in a cave as a child, eventually becomes leader of the sect

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I am looking for a manga where the kid is reborn in a demon sect and is trained in a cave as a child.

The child always wore shackles on his hands and legs, and after he grows up he becomes the leader of the sect.

Answer (score 2):

*Chronicles of Heavenly Demon*?

From [the manga's website](https://chroniclesofheavenlydemon.com):

> ‘You emphasized harmony your whole life and this is how you go…!’ The successor of the Spear Master Sect and his apprentice Hyuk Woon Seong were framed of learning a forbidden Demonic art and slayed. A helpless and pitiful death by the hypocrites of the Orthodox Sect. **The moment Woon Seong faced his death, The artifact of the Spear Master Sect emitted a light and gave him a new life. The life as Number 900, a trainee of the Demonic Cult!** The two identities, the Orthodox Sect and the Demonic Cult. But his objective is one. Vengeance! Accepting his destiny and remembering his grudge, **Woon Seong trains in martial arts And his time of revenge slowly comes closer….** Take over the Demonic Cult and punish the hypocrites of the Orthodox Sect! The revenge story of Number 900, Woon Seong growing in tasks of life and death.

In chapter 4, the reborn Woon Seong is seen wearing heavy bracers for training purposes:

[image: kid running up a mountain while wearing heavy metal bracers]

---

Found with the Google query `cultivation manga shackles sect` which led me to [this Reddit post asking for recommandations](https://www.reddit.com/r/Manhua/comments/kb4prd/cultivation_manhuamanhwa_where_the_mc_goes_to_an/), providing some titles as reference, which I browsed one after the other. *Chronicles of Heavenly Demon* was one of these mangas.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.